# How to change the zkclientTimeout in Solr cloud?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I have a Solr cloud instance and there are multiple cores.

There is a timeout issue happening so I want to increase the zkclientTimeout value for the Solr instance.

Normally these values are defined in solr.xml.

How can I change this value at the administration console?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be adding "-DzkClientTimeout=120000" to the Solr Server's JVM flags.